# wrapper class and normal string declaration gives same output?

Tags: java, string, wrapper

I tried below given examples

```
String s=new String("cat");
    String s1=new String("cat");
    System.out.println(s==s1);
    System.out.println(s.equals(s1));
```

this gives me output false and true.

```
String s="cat";
String s1="cat";
System.out.println(s==s1);
System.out.println(s.equals(s1));
```

in this case the output of both is true
may i know the difference between both
i heard both wrapper class and normal string declaration gives same output

Comment: `String` is not a wrapper class, and *please* don't use `new String()`.

Comment: Maybe not in the example above, but sometimes you want (and need) to use `new String()`. Even if `String` is not a _wrapper_ class, the question is valid.